# How to `apply` an `aggregate` all to multiple columns?

Tags: r, aggregate

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text="
Ratio col1 col2 col3 col4
0.3    1     1   1     1
0.4    1     1   1     2
0.5    1     1   2     1
0.6    2     2   1     1
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to summarize each pair of `Ratio` & `col`, similar to:

```
aggregate( Ratio ~ col1, data=df, mean)
aggregate( Ratio ~ col2, data=df, mean)
aggregate( Ratio ~ col3, data=df, mean)
aggregate( Ratio ~ col4, data=df, mean)
```

How would I rewrite this using one of the family of `apply` functions to calculate all the summaries? In the real world, this call will have to deal with a variable number of columns, i.e. `col1`, `col2`, ..., `coln`?

Comment: `lapply(2:ncol(df), function(i) aggregate(Ratio~., df[c(1, i)], mean))`

Comment: @d.b turn it to a answer man :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform your data in a "long" format, here an example with `data.table` (but that's also possible with `base` or `dplyr`/`tidyr`) :

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt <- melt(dt, measure.vars = paste0("col", 1:4))
dt[, mean(Ratio), by = list(value, variable)]
#    value variable        V1
# 1:     1     col1 0.4000000
# 2:     2     col1 0.6000000
# 3:     1     col2 0.4000000
# 4:     2     col2 0.6000000
# 5:     1     col3 0.4333333
# 6:     2     col3 0.5000000
# 7:     1     col4 0.4666667
# 8:     2     col4 0.4000000
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a great way of approaching it, as it places all the results in a format that makes down-stream processing a lot simpler

Comment: instead of `dt <- as.data.table(df)` , use `setDT(df)` and work with `df`. No need for an extra copy

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a job for `lapply`.

```
fmla_list <- lapply(names(df)[-1], function(x) as.formula(paste(names(df)[1], x, sep = "~")))

agg_list <- lapply(fmla_list, function(fmla) aggregate(fmla, data = df, FUN = mean))
names(agg_list) <- names(df)[-1]
agg_list
```

**EDIT.**

Like lmo says in his comment, you can also create the formulas list with the better

```
fmla_list <- lapply(names(df)[-1], function(x) reformulate(x, names(df)[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(names(df)[-1], function(x)
    data.frame(col = x,
               col_value = sapply(split(df[,x], df[,x]), unique),
               Ratio_mean = sapply(split(df$Ratio, df[,x]), mean))))
#    col col_value Ratio_mean
#1  col1         1  0.4000000
#2  col1         2  0.6000000
#11 col2         1  0.4000000
#21 col2         2  0.6000000
#12 col3         1  0.4333333
#22 col3         2  0.5000000
#13 col4         1  0.4666667
#23 col4         2  0.4000000
```